# Codeigniter configuration & debugging problem

Tags: codeigniter

I have changed my server with a project running on codeigniter. I already installed everything (PHP, MySQL, Codeigniter, etc) and all the processes seem to work fine.

But now I'm trying to connect to my project homepage, but I only receive a blank page.

It's not a rewrite problem (the Codeigniter index.php works fine...I can echo anything within the index.php). The database login is also correct.

Any ideas how to debug so that I can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

it was a CHMOD Problem:

the log folder was not writeable. the strange thing: both folders have CHMOD 755, but when I changed the folder to 777 the site works...